# Advantages and disadvantages of using Windows versus Linux print server?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, network-printer

I have a small network that I am building that looks like this:

[image]

The printer (center) is an old Laserjet 4si with JetDirect set to Ethernet. The machine connected to the BEFSX41 VPN hub is Windows XP and the machines connected to the Airport Express hub are Linux based. The JetDirect card in the 4si is the card made specifically for the 4si with 3 ports (BNC, LocalTalk and Ethernet).

My understanding is that to get the printer to work, I need to designate a PC as a print server. My three options as far as I can tell are:

(1) Have each machine be its own print server and connect to the printer directly. There is no risk of a collision because only one machine will be printing at any given time. However, there may be an issue of connecting and disconnecting different machines to the printer. I am not sure whether the JetDirect can support multiple simultaneous connections.

(2) Have the Windows XP box function as the print server.

(3) Have one of the Linux boxes connected to the Airport function as the printer server.

What are the relative advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: It has been ages, but IIRC a JetDirect card already is a print server, you don't need any others... You simply point your printer drivers at the IP-address of the JetDirect card.

Answer (score 4):

`My understanding is that to get the printer to work, I need to designate a PC as a print server`

The JetDirect card is a print server. You can connect each workstation directly to the printer via the printer ip address. All you need on the workstations is the appropriate printer driver.